# How to execute python scripts on mininet nodes?

Tags: mininet

I am just playing a little bit with mininet.
I created a topology and now I want to execute a http server on one of the nodes and simulate connections to it from the other nodes.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [mininet command line interface](http://mininet.org/walkthrough/#part-3-mininet-command-line-interface-cli-commands) to execute commands on nodes. For example, `h1 <cmd>` runs the command `<cmd>` on `h1`. You can also [spawn an xterm](http://mininet.org/walkthrough/#xterm-display) for each host by running mininet with the `-x` parameter (`sudo mn -x`). Either method allows you to run commands (including python scripts) on mininet nodes.